# Union-Find performance explanation

Tags: algorithm, union-find

This is with reference to the book Algorithm (Fouth Edition) by Robert Sedgewick & kevin Wayne

For Union-find implementation, the code for find and union is given as (page 222) as:

```
public int find(int p)
{
  return id[p]; 
}

public void union(int p, int q)
{ 
 // Put p and q into the same component.

 int pID = find(p);
 int qID = find(q);

// Nothing to do if p and q are already in the same component.

 if (pID == qID) return;

// Rename p’s component to q’s name.

 for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
      if (id[i] == pID) id[i] = qID;
 count--;
}
```

And then follows a proposition:

> Proposition F. The quick-find algorithm uses one array access for each
>   call to find() and between N + 3 and 2N + 1 array accesses for each
>   call to union() that combines two components.

I want to understand how did we actually arrive at **N + 3** and **2N + 1**. I have some idea about N + 3, but no idea about 2N + 1. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case that `pID != qID` we have:

2 accesses for:

```
int pID = find(p);
int qID = find(q);
```

and N accesses in the loop at the if-condition:

```
if (id[i] == pID)
```

so far N+2, but since `pID != qID` at least p has `pID!=qID` so we will access one more time inside if statement: `id[i] = qID;` so we will access array at least N+3 times.

In worst case that all N element have id `pID` we will execute `id[i] = qID;` N-1 times (not just once as before, N-1 because q has `qID` so we will not access array for q ) so overall: **2** + **N** (if condition in the for-loop for all N elements access) + **N-1** (for `id[i] = qID;` ) = **2N+1**.

Example:

if the array looks like: `qID qID qID pID qID` (5 elements)

then calling `union(1,4)` //1 index is the 1st element(with qID), 4 is the 4th(pID)

you will have 2 accesses in the beginning, 5 for if condition and only one if condition is true- for the 4 the element  which is the only one with pID so you have `2+5+1 =8= N+3` the minimum.

Now for example with max accesses take the array: `qID pID pID pID pID`
now you will have `2+5 + 4`(because four conditions are true) `= 11 = 2N+1` (N=8).

Comment: Hi @coder, I am able to understand it almost completely. However, can you please take an example (of both cases) and explain?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this sentence *so we will access array at least N=3 times* did you mean to write *so we will access array at least N+3 times*?

Comment: @RajaRaviVarma, I just reviewed the answer and yeah you are right, thanks for noticing! 
I have edited the answer